# Why doesn't the binary fraction representation match the decimal fraction representation?

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point

**The Problem:** What value does the hexadecimal number x55544552 represent in data type IEEE floating point?

**My Work**: 
     I first wrote out that hexadecimal number in binary and got

```
0101 0101 0101 0100 0100 0101 0101 0010
```

Now I have my three different sections, the sign, 0, the exponent 10101010 - 127, or 170 - 127, 43, and the fraction portion  101 0100 0100 0101 0101 0010, or 5522770.

Now I can write out my IEEE floating representation as 
        1.552270 $*$ 2 $^{43}$
   To simplify that expression, I decided to move the decimal point 23 slots to the right(the whole exponent proportion) and got 
   (1 101 0100 0100 0101 0101 0010) * 2 $^{20}$) or 13911378 * 2$^{20}$.

To me, all my math made sense. When I checked
my answer on  [Hex to IEEE Float](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html), everything matched up but I couldn't figure out this part on the web application.
The web application has a specified section called fraction which represents the fraction of the floating point representation. In binary, the fraction is 1 .10101000100010101010010 but in decimal, the web application says the fraction is 1.6583655. When I converted 10101000100010101010010 to decimal, I got 5522770. Shouldn't the fraction decimal representation be 1.5522770 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not how binary fractions work.
A decimal such as $0.13$ represents
$$0.13_{\mathrm{dec}} = 1\times 10^{-1} + 3\times10^{-2} = \frac{13}{100}\,.$$

Similarly, a binary fraction such as $0.1101$ represents
$$0.1101_{\mathrm{bin}} = 1\times 2^{-1} + 1\times 2^{-2} + 0\times 2^{-3} + 1\times2^{-4} = \frac{13}{16}\,.$$
$1101_{\mathrm{bin}} = 13_{\mathrm{dec}}$ but
$$0.1101_{\mathrm{bin}} = \frac{13}{16}\neq\frac{13}{100}=0.13_{\mathrm{dec}}\,.$$

Another way to see that you can't convert fractions into binary by forgetting that they're fractions is to note that $0.3=0.30$, but $3\neq 30$. So it can't possibly be that you convert $0.3$ in decimal to binary by saying "$3$ in binary is $11$, so $0.3$ in binary is $0.11$", since $0.3=0.30$ in decimal, so they should be equal in binary, too. But $30$ in binary is $11110$.

Comment: but isn't 0.11 in binary 1*2^-1 + 1*2^-2 which would be 0.75 decimal, not 0.3?

Comment: Exactly. As I said, "*it can't possibly be* that... 0.3 in binary is 0.11".